# netstandard code generator Microsoft.Data.SqlClient throwing FileNotFound System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=4.1.1.0

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn, c#-9.0

My netstandard 2.0 code generator being referenced from a core 5.0 console application.

The csproj looks like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Func" Version="0.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.2">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.8.0" PrivateAssets="all"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Generator dependencies -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.1.1" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <GetTargetPathDependsOn>$(GetTargetPathDependsOn);GetDependencyTargetPaths</GetTargetPathDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <Target Name="GetDependencyTargetPaths">
        <ItemGroup>
             <!--<TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGSystem_Security_Principal_Windows)\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />-->
             <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGMicrosoft_Data_SqlClient)\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

and references Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

when attempting to create a new `SqlConnection` like this

```
_dbConnection = new SqlConnection();           
_dbConnection.ConnectionString = @"validconnectionstring";
_dbConnection.Open();
```

On the open of the connection an Exception is thrown with message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Stacktrace:
at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity.GetCurrentNative()
at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup.GetConnectionPool(DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPool(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionPoolGroup connectionPoolGroup)
at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
at CSharp.Data.Sql.Schema.Provider.SqlServer.DbConnectionAsync..ctor() in C:\Dev\CSharpSQLProvider\SQLProvider\CSharp.Data.Sql\Schema\Provider\SqlServer\DbConnectionAsync.cs:line 18
at CSharp.Data.Sql.Generator.DataContextGenerator.Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context) in C:\Dev\CSharpSQLProvider\SQLProvider\CSharp.Data.Sql\Generator\DataContextGenerator.cs:line 57
```

Innerexception is null.

To be clear, I am able to create an instance of SqlConnection just when setting the connection string this error is thrown. I also tried the System.Data.SqlClient, however I wasn't able to create a SqlConnection instance but the same exception was thrown just with a different assembly name.

I have also tried adding the dependency into the csproj in the same way as I have for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in the example given to no avail, also attempted to load the required assemblies into the app domain, and also tried adding the assembly into the context compilation.

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\{user}\.nuget\packages\system.security.principal.windows\4.4.1\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll");

 var refe = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(assembly.Location);
 var foo = context.Compilation.ExternalReferences.Add(refe);
var d = context.Compilation.AddReferences(new[] { refe });
```

I suspect I'm doing something wrong and any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I should also mention that the missing assembly is apart of the returned assemblies in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() within the execute method

Comment: simply add [the package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Principal.Windows) to the application

Comment: That doesn't work, this isnt runtime this is compile time and you have to use msbuild in csproj to do that with <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker see also https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/master/samples/CSharp/SourceGenerators/SourceGeneratorSamples/SourceGeneratorSamples.csproj it's not as simple as adding the reference

Comment: I'm hitting the same issues when trying to use SqlClient in an analyzer. The issue is that you need to pull in the correct dependencies for the compilation-runtime. My hunch is that the a Build of the package is not enough. The analyzer needs everything from a Publish (with the RuntimeIdentifier of the current compiler-platform - especially the contents of the runtimes folders), in order to function correctly.

Comment: It seems strange to me that you're combining .NET Standard 2.0 and C# 9. AFAIK this is not a valid configuration

Comment: You can combine netstandard2.0 and C#9 if you wish. It just may happen to create issues that are hard to figure out. If you don't use unsupported syntax, all is fine.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a new,clean solution you can upload to github?

Answer (score 0):

you can map the required assembly to the required version in app.config like below .

```
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Principal.Windows" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly
```

Comment: What if there is no app.config file? this is for a netstandard 2.0 project.

Comment: Add the mapping in  the .net 5 client application from where the .net standard assembly is called

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't work. I added an app.config to the console app so the xml looks like ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Principal.Windows" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</configuration>``` However same issue when the console app is built and the code generator runs

Comment: Did you check whether the config file generated after building the project has the mapping

Comment: I don't think I understand. To be clear this isn't a normal project this is a c#9 code generator and the libraries have to be referenced at compile time rather than runtime. The console app didn't have a app.config file generated, I created one and added the XML you gave (thank you btw).

Comment: You have to use msbuild to add references during compile time running of the generator, see these samples https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/master/samples/CSharp/SourceGenerators/SourceGeneratorSamples/SourceGeneratorSamples.csproj as an example